# Automatic change of 2 related input fields?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, opencart

I want to modify an existing form in my website. The concerned form allows me to introduce discount prices for some of my articles for a limited period of time at my admin panel (see image). The data of the table are populated via a mysql database. I'm using the open source ecommerce software Opencart.

[image]

Untill now, I could only introduce the prices without tax in the column "prijs". Now I have added an additional column "Pricevatinc". The goal is that I would also be able to introduce the prices including taxes in the column "Pricevatinc". The ratio between "prijs" (without tax) and "pricevatinc" (with tax) is simply a factor of 1.21.

So if I introduce 100 in the column "Pricevatinc", than the column "price" should change to 82.6446 immediately. Similarly, when I introduce 100 in the column "prijs" than the column "pricevatinc" should change immediately to 121.
Once all data have been entered, I will click on the "Bewaren" button to save all data to the database.

The existing piece of code in my template is added below, but I'm not skilled enough to make the necessary modifications in javascript or other language. I would be very pleased if you could look at my piece of code and suggest the necessary changes or help me in the right direction....

Thanks,
SabKo

Script code:

```
    case 'specials': ?>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="specials">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_customer_group; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right"><?php echo $entry_priority; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right"><?php echo $entry_price; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><?php echo $entry_pricevatinc2; ?></td>
                <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_date_start; ?></td>
                <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_date_end; ?></td>
                <td width="1"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $special_row = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($product_specials as $product_special) { ?>
            <tr id="special-row<?php echo $special_row; ?>">
                <td class="text-left"><select name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][customer_group_id]" class="form-control">
                        <?php foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) { ?>
                        <?php if ($customer_group['customer_group_id'] == $product_special['customer_group_id']) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select></td>
                <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][priority]" value="<?php echo $product_special['priority']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_priority; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][price]" value="<?php echo $product_special['price']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][pricevatinc]" value="<?php echo $product_special['pricevatinc']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_pricevatinc2; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date">
                    <input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][date_start]" value="<?php echo $product_special['date_start']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_start; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span></div></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date">
                    <input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][date_end]" value="<?php echo $product_special['date_end']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_end; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span></div></td>
                <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(this).tooltip('destroy');$('#special-row<?php echo $special_row; ?>').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php $special_row++; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="addSpecial();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_special_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var special_row = <?php echo $special_row; ?>;
function addSpecial() {
    html  = '<tr id="special-row' + special_row + '">';
    html += '  <td class="text-left"><select name="product_special[' + special_row + '][customer_group_id]" class="form-control">';
    <?php foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) { ?>
    html += '      <option value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo addslashes($customer_group['name']); ?></option>';
    <?php } ?>
    html += '  </select></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][priority]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_priority; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][price]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][pricevatinc]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_pricevatinc2; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][date_start]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_start; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][date_end]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_end; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#special-row' + special_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('#specials tbody').append(html);
    $('#special-row' + special_row + ' .date').datetimepicker({pickTime: false  });
    $('#special-row' + special_row + ' [data-toggle=\'tooltip\']').tooltip({container: 'body'});
    special_row++;
}
$('#specials tbody .date').datetimepicker({pickTime: false});
//--></script>
```

Unfortunately, the solution supplied by Poletaew (see in answers) is not working properly in my site. I suppose there might be a conflict with some other jquery or javascript files defined in the headers of my website. Or maybe the jquery does not get activated when the form is showing up as a popup? I have placed the link to the jquery script in my header or just in the html template page just above the script, but nothing helps.

Are there any workarounds or alternatives that I could try? This keeps me busy already 2 evenings :-(.

This the code I have based on Poletaew's suggestion:

```
    case 'specials': ?>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="specials">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_customer_group; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right"><?php echo $entry_priority; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right"><?php echo $entry_price; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right"><?php echo $entry_pricevatinc2; ?></td>
                <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_date_start; ?></td>
                <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_date_end; ?></td>
                <td width="1"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $special_row = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($product_specials as $product_special) { ?>
            <tr id="special-row<?php echo $special_row; ?>">
                <td class="text-left"><select name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][customer_group_id]" class="form-control">
                        <?php foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) { ?>
                        <?php if ($customer_group['customer_group_id'] == $product_special['customer_group_id']) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select></td>
                <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][priority]" value="<?php echo $product_special['priority']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_priority; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][price]" value="<?php echo $product_special['price']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price; ?>" class="pricevatexc" /></td>
                <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][pricevatinc]" value="<?php echo $product_special['pricevatinc']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_pricevatinc2; ?>" class="pricevatinc" /></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date">
                    <input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][date_start]" value="<?php echo $product_special['date_start']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_start; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span></div></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date">
                    <input type="text" name="product_special[<?php echo $special_row; ?>][date_end]" value="<?php echo $product_special['date_end']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_end; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span></div></td>
                <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(this).tooltip('destroy');$('#special-row<?php echo $special_row; ?>').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php $special_row++; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"></td>
                <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="addSpecial();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_special_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var special_row = <?php echo $special_row; ?>;

function addSpecial() {
    html  = '<tr id="special-row' + special_row + '">';
    html += '  <td class="text-left"><select name="product_special[' + special_row + '][customer_group_id]" class="form-control">';
    <?php foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) { ?>
    html += '      <option value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo addslashes($customer_group['name']); ?></option>';
    <?php } ?>
    html += '  </select></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][priority]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_priority; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][price]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price; ?>" class="form-control pricevatexc" /></td>';
    //Loulie
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][pricevatinc]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_pricevatinc2; ?>" class="form-control pricevatinc" /></td>';
    //Einde Loulie
    html += '  <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][date_start]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_start; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-left" style="width: 20%;"><div class="input-group date"><input type="text" name="product_special[' + special_row + '][date_end]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_end; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#special-row' + special_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#specials tbody').append(html);

    $('#special-row' + special_row + ' .date').datetimepicker({pickTime: false  });

    $('#special-row' + special_row + ' [data-toggle=\'tooltip\']').tooltip({container: 'body'});

    special_row++;
}
$('#specials tbody .date').datetimepicker({pickTime: false});
//--></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var rate = 1.21;
$(document).on('keyup', '.pricevatexc', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find('.pricevatinc').val(val * rate)
})
$(document).on('keyup', '.pricevatinc', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find('.pricevatexc').val(val / rate)
})
//--></script>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle and show the issue

Comment: Hello Yo Yo, I tried to setup a jsfiddle but the outcome is very poor (have not used it before and my website is not online yet so I can't setup external resources). So it seems complex to me at this moment. Anyway, I will try to find out how it works because it might be interesting for future issues. Rgeards, SaKko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is solution:

```js
var rate = 1.21;

$(document).on('keyup', '.prijs', function(){
 var val = $(this).val();
    
 $(this).parent().find('.pricevatinc').val(val * rate)
})

$(document).on('keyup', '.pricevatinc', function(){
 var val = $(this).val();
    
 $(this).parent().find('.prijs').val(val / rate)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p>
        <input class="prijs" value="100"> <input class="pricevatinc" value="121">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="prijs" value="82"> <input class="pricevatinc" value="100">
    </p>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4h37q7p9/

You can adapt it for themselves, but the general logic should be clear.

Comment: Hello Poletaew, thank you for the code snippet. This seems to be exactly what I want. I'm impatient to try to implement it in my website later today. I will let you know if it works. Thank you very much for your help. Regards. SabKo

Comment: Hello Poletaew, I finally got it working. My mistake was that the 2 concerned inputs were placed into two different parents (td tag) while they need to be in the same "parent" like your code suggests. Thanks for your contribution! SabKo

Comment: Hi, i glade to help you. Also you could get "tr" (`$(this).parents('tr')` or `$(this).parent().parent()`).